# Generic jqueryui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a number of places in my website where I have a jqueryui dialog. In many cases the jquery code is almost identical. Typical differences are for title, width, and height.

The dialog is attached to a control with something like $('#selector').dialog().

Is there a way to make this like a "function that is called with parameters"? That is, have a generic jquery function instead of have numerous nearly identical codes?

Answer (score -1):

You can try below code for generic function for dialog.

```
<button id="btn1" onclick="GenericDialog('Title 1',300,250)">Open the dialog</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="GenericDialog('Title 2',200,150)">Open the dialog</button>
<div id="dia">
<p>Some txt goes here</p>
</div>

$('#dia').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Basic Dialog'
});

function GenericDialog(title,width,height){
    $("#dia").dialog({ 
        width: width, 
        height: height, 
        title: title})
    .dialog('open');
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask for votes here - we prefer it to be organic. It's OK to explain, in comments, how to use the voting system, if you think a specific person does not know how/when to do it.

Comment: I will have to think about this, to see if (1) I can adapt it to my environment; (2) if it achieves the result of eliminating almost redundant code. At first glance it appears that it replaces the definition of the whole dialog with the smaller definition of just the click(function) attached to each button. That is an improvement, but still not as "functional" as I am looking for--that may not exist and the approach from Nandan Rathod may be as close as we can get.

Comment: @JeffreySimon: Also, you can directly call this function from button tag.

Comment: If I understand your last post, you would define the dialog in the first jquery snippet, and define the function GenericDialog(). Then you would omit all the jquery attached to the buttons, of which there would be many. Instead you would have an onclick=GenericDialog(title, width,height). I am thinking that is an optimal solution. If this works, you should put your comment into an answer so I can award points.

Comment: @JeffreySimon I have updated the above answer

Comment: I can't speak for moderators, but it is my experience that re-adding requests for votes where that has already been taken out will result in those post(s) being locked. It really is the case that this material does not belong here. If you are in any doubt, you can always ask for an opinion about it on Meta Stack Overflow.